# big query - array_agg nested within array_concat doesn't support ignore nulls properly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I don't know if this is expected behaviour, but it seems pretty buggy to me:

If you run this query...

```
select array_concat( 
   array_agg(x)
)
from unnest([1,2,3,4]) as x
```

You get one row with an array of `[1,2,3,4]`, which is expected.

If you add in an empty array, you get the same single row with `[1,2,3,4]` as expected...

```
select array_concat( 
   array_agg(x),
   []
)
from unnest([1,2,3,4]) as x
```

However if you add in `array_agg(null ignore nulls)`, the whole thing breaks...

```
select array_concat( 
   array_agg(x),
   array_agg(null ignore nulls)
)
from unnest([1,2,3,4]) as x
```

this returns an empty array!

If the above simplified example looks strange, consider this instead, which works for `x=4`, and totally breaks for `x=5`

```
select array_concat( 
   array_agg(x),
   array_agg(case when x = 4 then x end ignore nulls)
)
from unnest([1,2,3,4]) as x
```

*Question:* is this expected? If so, why? If not, is anyone aware of an existing bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior and here's why:

First, this query returns `null` instead of empty array

```
select array_concat( 
   array_agg(x),
   array_agg(null ignore nulls)
)
from unnest([1,2,3,4]) as x
```

[array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) document says: `If there are zero input rows, this function returns NULL.`, therefore, array_agg(null ignore nulls) => null.

[array_concat](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_concat) says `The function returns NULL if any input argument is NULL.`

so the above query end up looking like:

```
array_concat( 
   array_agg(x),
   null,
)
```

It is expected to return null to you.

If you're relying on some library which transforms the query result for you. The library may treat NULL array as empty array, this may be a problematic behavior.

Comment: Returning NULL when input argument is NULL is quite common in SQL world. In SQL, NULL is not empty but "I don't know what it is!"

Answer (score 1):

> If the above simplified example looks strange, consider this instead, which works for x=4, and totally breaks for x=5

As you [hopefully] realized already - the behavior you see is as expected and is by design, so I will not repeat what already answered :o)

Meantime, I think, what you really need here - is just to rewrite your case into some thing like below

```
select array_concat_agg( 
   [x]  || 
   array(select x from unnest(['whatever']) where x = 4)
)
from unnest([1,2,3,4]) as x
```

with output

[image]

and now  - if you replace `x = 4` with `x = 5`

```
select array_concat_agg( 
   [x]  || 
   array(select x from unnest(['whatever']) where x = 5)
)
from unnest([1,2,3,4]) as x
```

the output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you read the documentation for array_concat it states “The function returns NULL if any input argument is NULL” - so the behavior you are seeing is what is expected.

BTW an empty array is not the same as null